# Unecessary assignment of a value c# when using out

Tags: c#, out

I recently came up to the following Message with the code below

```
string errorMessage = String.Empty;
```

I've been getting:

> Message   **IDE0059** Unnecessary assignment of a value to 'errorMessage'

The only place this is used was

```
var valid = IsValid(out errorMessage);
```

Why am I getting this Message?

Comment: Why assign at all? `string errorMessage;` works

Comment: @SeM I changed the Warning to Message. @Panagiotis Kanavos - I was wondering why `string errorMessage` works. Since I figured it out, I thought to share with the community.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras what you posted doesn't even compile though. It's not mandatory to assign a value to the *variable*, it's mandatory to assign a value to the parameter

Comment: What do you mean? In the question or in the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't set the initial value. This is perfectly valid code :

```
string errorMessage;
var valid = IsValid(out errorMessage);
```

Or use

```
var valid=IsValid(out var errorMessage);
```

The compiler *knows* that the variable is used as an `out` parameter and will get a value unless an exception is thrown.

On the other hand, `IsValid` *has* to store a value in the out parameter, overwriting any initial value. The original value is never used, and so doesn't need to be assigned.

This won't compile :

```
public bool IsValid(out string errorMessage) {
   return true;
}
```

and return :

> CS0177 The out parameter 'errorMessage' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

This will work  :

```
public bool IsValid(out string errorMessage) {
   errorMessage="";
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that message needs explanation, it basically says that *the value that you've assigned to `errorMessage` is unnecessary, because you have never used that (`errorMessage`) variable*.

In that case, if you never planning to use `errorMessage` variable, you can use one handy tool, called [Discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards), so you can write:

```
bool value = IsValid(out _);
```

Comment: I am using the variable. This is not the reason why. Check mine and Panagiotis explanations below.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras the question says that the variable is never used : `The only place this is used was ...`. This is a very good answer that **should** be upvoted.

Comment: Why was this dowvnoted? I wish I had thought of this first

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not sure why, any explanation guys?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras Assigning variable and actually using it is not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry m8, tunnel vision. I had something specific in mind. It is indeed a very worthy answer! My bad for not phrasing the question in a better way to convey the initial intent.

Answer (score 0):

The .net compiler forces us to assign a value to any `out` parameter in the function getting the variable with the `out` modifier.

So in the example below:

```
public bool IsValid(out string errorMessage) {
   return true;
}
```

We would get the error

> **Error   CS0177**    The out parameter 'errorMessage' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method   ServicesUtils

Since it's mandatory to assign a value, the compiler is clever enough to warn us of a redundant assignment beforehand, which will be overriden in a mandatory way.

This way we are protected from being misled by the initial assignment.

Comment: Or you could use `out var`. Or *not* assign anything - `string errorMessage;` works

Comment: In the example `IsValid` won't even compile because `errorMessage` is never assigned. `IsValid` *has* to put something in there, even if it's a `null`

Comment: This is what I'm saying. The fact that it will provide an error is why I'm getting the Message in the first place.